# Problem with AWS Web Application Firewall

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, web-application-firewall

I have an AWS EC2 instance (single machine) + Elastic IP + Route 53 (redirects the domain name to my EC2 machine).

I wanted to add AWS Web Application Firewall. So the configuration is:
EC2 instance + Application Load Balancer with Web Application Firewall + Route 53 (redirects the domain name to the load balancer).

However, with this new configuration, my Ajax scripts fail to execute. For example, the code

```js
'use strict';

var url = require('url');
var target = 'https://DOMAIN_NAME';

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  var urlObject = url.parse(target);
  var mod = require(
    urlObject.protocol.substring(0, urlObject.protocol.length - 1)
  );
  console.log('[INFO] - Checking ' + target);
  var req = mod.request(urlObject, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      console.log('[INFO] - Read body chunk');
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log('[INFO] - Response end');
      callback();
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('[ERROR] - ' + e.message);
    callback(e);
  });
  req.end();
};
```

fails with "This combination of host and port requires TLS".

Some other Ajax requests fail too.

I've opened ports 80, 22, and 443 on the EC2 instance. And port 443 is opened in the Load Balancer.

I don't understand why these script fail with the new configuration. In the old configuration everything works fine.

UPDATE: It seems that one of the rules in the AWS WAF Core Rule Set is blocking my ajax requests. I guess, I'll just need to find out which one.

Comment: Do you have a diff to share between the old and new config?

Comment: @AnthonyMiller I'm using the AWS web interface to configure my website. So "config" here is not a file. I'm not sure how can I share it.

Comment: Without knowing what the config was before, and just going off of the error output, there's likely a need to specify the use of TLS in your configuration. You may wish to check if there's a way to specify a TLS protocol in your configuration (i.e. TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2, etc.)

Comment: @aleksmath Did you ever find out which Core Rule Set rules were matching? If you have access to logging information, you can get the IDs of the offending rules and then create a rule exclusion to handle the false positives. That will resolve your issue properly going forward.

Comment: @xanadu Yes. Some of my URL requests were quite big which would trigger some WAF rules. So I turned off those rules. I didn't look into logging information though, so I had to switch on and off all the rules one by one.

Comment: @aleksmath Oh dear: sounds arduous! Should you run into a similar issue again, be sure to grab logging info and post to Stack Overflow. If you use the key words "Core Rule Set" then myself or a fellow CRS developer should see it and be able to assist.

Comment: @xanadu Thank you! Next time I'll know to look into the logging info. I should have done it in the first place I guess.